# In Python, how do I get the path to a directory of files located within a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a module called 'playr' that has a subdirectory of wav files:

```
user/repositories/python_packages/playr/
|
|--__init__.py
|--sounds/
|   |--sound1.wav
|   |--sound2.wav
|   |--sound3.wav
```

In my `__init__.py` is a function that should get a list of all the files in the `sounds/` directory in order to play a selected sound:

```
from os import listdir
import os.path
import subprocess

def play(sound=0):
    wav_files = listdir('sounds')
    sound_file = os.path.join('sounds', wav_files[sound])
    return_code = subprocess.call(['afplay', sound_file])
```

Because I'd like to share this module, **I need to find a way to get the path to the `sounds/` directory without hardcoding the absolute path**. The parent directory `user/repositories/python_packages/` is included in my `PYTHONPATH` variable.

Currently, when I attempt to use the module from a python env in a different directory, it goes like this:

```
from playr import play

play()


----------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sounds'
```

I understand it's not finding the `sounds/` directory because it's looking in my current environment and not within the module. **My question is how can I get my function to look within the module instead of the current environment**.

So far I've tried many different methods using `os.path` and `pathlib`. I've also attempted different ways of using `module.__file__`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

#### UPDATE

My current solution is using `pathlib.Path(__file__)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT [2022-01-12]:
I updated my approach with a much simpler solution using `pathlib.Path(__file__)`, which returns the full PosixPath to the file in the package directory, and from there it's easy to navigate to the desired subdirectory. This was much easier, it didn't require additional packages installed, and works just fine for me with Python 3.6 - 3.10

I put the following in `__init__.py`

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(__file__)
sounds_dir = p.parent / 'sounds'

def beep(sound=2):
    sounds = [x for x in sounds_dir.iterdir()]
    return_code = subprocess.call(['afplay', sounds[sound]])
```

To use, I made sure to add the finished package (renamed to [`beepr`](https://github.com/tmcfl/beepr)) to my PYTHONPATH and I've had no issues using it like so:

```
from beepr import beep
beep(2)
```

---

Here's the (previous) solution I'd used that needed [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) and worked with Python 3.7 & 3.8, or the backport [`importlib_resources`](https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to work with < 3.7

```
# py 3.7
import os, subprocess
from importlib.resources import path

def play(sound=0):
    with path('playr', 'sounds') as sounds_path:
        sounds = os.listdir(sounds_path)
        audio_file = os.path.join(sounds_path, sounds[sound])
        return_code = subprocess.call(['afplay', audio_file])
```

But again, besides being less straightfoward, it also didn't work with Python 3.9 or 3.10

---

Comment: The documentation of `path` says about the second parameter (resource):
`resource is the name of the resource to open within package; it may not contain path separators and it may not have sub-resources (i.e. it cannot be a directory)`
i.e. it doesn't work with `sounds`.

Comment: It worked with Python versions < 3.9 (though it already shouldn't have according to the documentation..).

Comment: Well, it definitely doesn't work in 3.9... How is this supposed to be done if you have data in a subdirectory of a package?

Comment: For python 3.9 or 3.10, you can make the subdirectory a subpackage by adding the `__init__.py`.
Then you can get the resource with `with path('package.subpackage', 'file') as resource: ...`

Comment: @Vorticity I updated my answer to use `pathlib`, which was more simple and also compatible with Python 3.6 through 3.10.

Answer (score 2):

`os.path.abspath(__file__)` returns the full pathname to the current module file, i.e. something like `/foo/bar/baz/module.py`.

`os.path.dirname(fullpath)` chops off the filename and just returns the directory, i.e. `/foo/bar/baz`.

So, you want:

`os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'sounds')`